# Best way to go towards an index in numpy, with wrap

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Lets say I have a 2D array below:

```
 [[ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 2 ]
  [ 0 1 0 0 0 0 ]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]]
```

I would like to get the direction from where '1' (index 4,1) is to '2' (index 3,5). Assuming directions are only up, down, left, right.  Thus no diagonal movement.

One way to get the directions:

```
"right" if destination.x > start.x else "left" if target.x < start.x else None

"down" if destination.y > start.y else "up" if destination.y < start.y else None
```

So for this example, we can go to '2' or the destination by either going "up" or "right".  That of course is just one step, once you moved, can perform the same logic to move closer to the destination.

The problem with this logic is that it doesnt take the wrapping into account.  With this logic it will take 5 steps to get to the destination. There is a shorter way by actually going left or up that can get to the destination in just 3 steps, because of the wrap.

Was thinking of generating another array where the start will be the middle of the array and perform the same logic.  The problem is if the array is even (like this is 6x6, need to pad to get a middle.  For example:

```
 [[ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [ 0 2 0 0 0 0 0]
  [ 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Here the array is now 7x7.  I believe there is a simplier way to get the answer without this extra step, but cant think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider using this method?

```
import numpy as np

# build the array
a = np.zeros( (6,6), dtype=int )
a[4][1] = 1
a[3][5] = 2

# extract required informations
i,j = np.where(a == 1)
h,k =np.where(a == 2)

print (i-h) => [1]
print (j-k) => [-4]
```

Comment: Not sure if i get your answer.  Are you saying to use the same logic I had but have 1, -4 as the new destination?  If so yes for this scenario this works, where it'll tell me to go "left" or "up" instead.  But in a scenario where "1" is located in 4,1 and "2" at 3, 2 it should go "up" or "right", where using your logic will give "left" or "up" where left is actually going away

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a quite simple formula for computing the distance in case of periodic boundary conditions. Below I consider only periodic b.c. on x-axis:

```
import numpy as np

# periodic boundary condition for the x-axis only
def steps(start, dest, L_x):
    x_start = start[1]
    y_start = start[0]
    x_dest = dest[1]
    y_dest = dest[0]

    dx = x_dest - x_start
    if np.abs(dx) <= L_x/2:
        steps_x = x_dest - x_start
    else:
        if dx > 0:
            steps_x = (x_dest - L_x) - x_start
        else:
            steps_x = (x_dest + L_x) - x_start            

    steps_y = y_dest - y_start

    return steps_x, steps_y
```

Example:

```
grid = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 ],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]])

L_x = grid.shape[1]    
start = (4, 1)  # (y, x) or (i, j)
dest = (3, 5)

steps_x, steps_y = steps(start, dest, grid)
dir_x = 'left' if steps_x < 0 else 'right'
dir_y = 'up' if steps_y < 0 else 'down'
print(abs(steps_x), dir_x, ',', abs(steps_y), dir_y)

Out: 2 left , 1 up
```

Answer (score 0):

I try an other way:

On an horizontal  axis of length `size`, to go from `a` to `b`, let `delta = ((b-a)%size*2-1)//size`.

- if `delta=-1`, `a=b` : you don't move.
- if `delta=0` : you have to go right.
- if `delta=1` : you have to go left.

So this code seems works

```
size=10
vertical=['down','up',None]
horizontal=['right','left',None]

def side(a,b):
    return ((b-a)%size*2-1)//size

def step(M1,M2):
    x1,y1=M1
    x2,y2=M2
    return (vertical[side(x1,x2)],horizontal[side(y1,y2)])
```

For example :

```
In [6]: step((2,1),(2,8))
Out[6]: (None, 'left')
```